# Is there sample data to populate developer edition?

Tags: app-development, import

I love coding in the development edition of Salesforce. However I find it rather annyoing to fill in sample data for accounts, contacts, cases, etc. all by myself.

I wonder whether there is sample data avalaible somewhere that I can import and use in my DE.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: When you start a dev org, it already has some sample data. Are you looking for more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developer edition is generated from a DOT (Default Organizational Template) that has a set of data populated for common objects.  For example, I have the following and more in my accounts list as soon as the org is enabled:

```
Burlington Textiles Corp of America
Genepoint
Grand Hotels and Resorts of America
```

Plus I have associated contacts, opportunities and cases.

If you don't have these it implies you are in a developer or configuration sandbox, which contains a copy of your production configuration, but no data.

You can create a set of default data to load into a sandbox (or other edition) - I've found its best to define external ids for parent records so that I don't have to upload accounts, then retrieve them and fix up the id on each contact, opportunity and case.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized, that I worked on a sandbox all the time, not an DE. Problem solved!