# I have a Salesforce Developer account. How do I enable sample data (contacts, accounts, organizations, opportunities, etc.)?

Tags: data

Rather than entering dummy data into my developer account, I read in [another post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/is-there-sample-data-to-populate-developer-edition?newreg=50b43cf4ddca452692949a4f0a12bb96), that you can use sample data that is already built into Dev accounts, but I don't know how to turn it on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The sample data is already there when you first activate the DE Org. There should be a selection of Accounts, Contacts, Cases, Leads, Opportunities and a few others. If you go to any of those tabs you can see what is there with different views. Also if you look under Setup > Data Management > Storage Usage you can see the number of record already present in different objects.